# Return String array

Tags: c++, c

I don't know if this question is asked. But I couldn't find any clear answer after searching full day on net. I would like to return a string array from a function. Right now I can make a String array by splitting a string.

I am new to this but familiar with Java, very hard to split a string though. I tried as below. Someone please make a function out of it which can be used thru out.

```
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Starting..");
 // Define 
  String txt = "A@10,20,30:B@40,50,60:B@70,80,90:A@100,110,120"; 
  int str_len = txt.length() + 1; 
  char char_array[str_len];
  txt.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);

  Serial.println(char_array);

  char *p = char_array;
  char *str;
  int i=0;
  String arr[20];
  while ((str = strtok_r(p, ":", &p)) != NULL) {// delimiter is the semicolon
    String stringOne =  String(str);
    arr[i++]=stringOne;
  }
}
void loop(){}
```

Also is it possible to make String array "arr" size dynamic?

Comment: you should use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).  It has methods to split and maniuplate the characters within the string.

Comment: In C, you're probably best off returning a dynamically allocated structure and relying on the caller to free it. C++ has other methods I can't speak to.

Comment: error: 'string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @Aadam: `#include <string>`

Comment: I got that after #include <string>

Comment: Can i get a simple example?

Comment: I don't see any return values so I'm not sure where you want to return a string array. You should use `std::vector<std::string>` for a dynamic array of strings. Or replace with `String` if this is the type you want to use.

Comment: This std is irritating..... Anyway the whole world is distraught with it :p